# Google's dense_hash_map crashing in set_empty_key() function

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to use google dense_hash_map to store key value data instead of std:map.

When I tested with (int, int ) pair, I set the set_empty_key(mymap, -2) and it worked.

But, now when I use it with my (hash, value) pair, I set the set_empty_key (mymap -2) or set_empty_key(mymap, some_random_hash), in both the cases my program crashes in set_empty_key();.

Anyone can guide me with this? How can I fix this crash?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `key_type` in the second case?  `set_empty_key()` naturally expects a value of `key_type` (thereafter "banned" from the map), not always an integer.  Somewhat related: see [MCT](https://launchpad.net/libmct/) for a hash table library without empty/deleted key limitation.

Comment: In teh second case the key_type is my custom type key (Not default type). My question is what should I pass as the key for 'set_empty_key(map, key)'. If I try to pass 0, it does not accept saying it is an interger and if I pass some random key of my custom type it crashes at asserts in 'assert(settings.use_empty());'in 'densehashtable.h'

Comment: I haven't used Google's Sparsehashlib all that much.  You are supposed to use any value of `key_type` as an empty key, *but* not use that value as a real key afterwards.  The same for deleted key.  I.e. you need to single out one or two values and set them as empty and, optionally, as deleted key.  Also, the empty key must be set before anything is ever inserted in the table, AFAIR.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know the exact reason of crash you've got, but, based on your description I see at least two potential mistakes.

First. Check that both `key_type` and `data_type` types are POD types and don't contain pointers to itself. More specifically ([original](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/dense_hash_map.html#7)):

> Both key_type and data_type must be
>   plain old data. In addition, there should
>   be no data structures that point
>   directly into parts of key or value,
>   including the key or value itself (for
>   instance, you cannot have a value like
>   struct {int a = 1, *b = &a}. This is
>   because dense_hash_map uses malloc()
>   and free() to allocate space for the
>   key and value, and memmove() to
>   reorganize the key and value in
>   memory.

Second. Concerning using dense_hash_map. You need to set up some special "empty" key value which will never be used for real elements stored in your collection. Moreover if you are going to use `erase()` you need to specify special key for deleted items which also will never be used as key for real stored items.
That is perfectly described [here](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/dense_hash_map.html#6):

> dense_hash_map requires you call
>   set_empty_key() immediately after
>   constructing the hash-map, and before
>   calling any other dense_hash_map
>   method. (This is the largest
>   difference between the dense_hash_map
>   API and other hash-map APIs. See
>   implementation.html for why this is
>   necessary.) The argument to
>   set_empty_key() should be a key-value
>   that is never used for legitimate
>   hash-map entries. If you have no such
>   key value, you will be unable to use
>   dense_hash_map. It is an error to call
>   insert() with an item whose key is the
>   "empty key." dense_hash_map also
>   requires you call set_deleted_key()
>   before calling erase(). The argument
>   to set_deleted_key() should be a
>   key-value that is never used for
>   legitimate hash-map entries. It must
>   be different from the key-value used
>   for set_empty_key(). It is an error to
>   call erase() without first calling
>   set_deleted_key(), and it is also an
>   error to call insert() with an item
>   whose key is the "deleted key."